# Comparing ius sacrum and fas

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison, legal-latin, religio

I would like clarification on two related divine and legal terms: *ius sacrum* and *fas*.
They can both be translated as "divine law", but I do not think they are the same thing.
I have an idea of what they might be, but I would like confirmation or correction of my ideas.
Is the following paragraph — which is not a quote from anyone but just my own thoughts — a good description of what *ius sacrum* and *fas* meant in classical antiquity?

> There are two words for justice, *ius* and *fas*.
>   *Ius* is justice as we commonly know it: man creates laws and ensures that they are followed.
>   Breaking *ius* is a matter between mortals.
>   *Fas* is divine justice: gods decide what is right and they punish those who break it.
>   *Fas* also describes days suitable for various affairs.
>   I might call *pietas* "doing what *fas* requires".
>   In this sense *ius* is "human law" and *fas* is "divine law".
>   Of course it was in the interest of the society to avoid the wrath of gods (whether out of true spirituality or as a political tool), so people were interested in making sure *fas* was followed.
>   This is what *ius sacrum* is for: it is man-made law concerning religion.
>   *Fas* is "law made by gods about human behaviour" and *ius sacrum* is "law made by humans about maintaining human–god relations".
>   They are "divine law" in very different ways.

Comment: Great question: note that there are [at least 20 occurrences](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ius+fasque) of "ius fasque," almost half from Livy, so the two certainly have an intersection of *reference*, if not meaning.

Comment: Related publication (Fr): http://www.jstor.org/stable/43844186?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: It seems as if "ius" refers to a law, described by "sacram" to be sacred, but "fas" can also mean what is moral or allowed. I would answer this, but I'm not too sure about how the Latins would ever use the two or if they are interchangeable.

Comment: Great question! This distinction was good to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent research has shed some new light on this question. A [dissertation](https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/23426/) that came out of Rutgers in 2007 called the whole idea of *ius sacrum* into question.

Johnson takes a look at the evidence behind the standard interpretation. For reference, for years everyone relied on Adolf Berger's article in the [*RE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realencyclop%C3%A4die_der_classischen_Altertumswissenschaft) and, later, his entry in *Encyclopedia Dictionary of Roman Law*, which I produce below:

> Ius Sacrum. Strictly connected with *ius divinum* and *ius pontificum*. It embraces the legal principles and institutions which are connected with the relations of men to gods, with questions of cult, sacrifices, temples, consecrations, graves, and sacerdotal functions, whenever they may occur. The jurists Servius Sulpicius and Trebatius wrote on the subject of the *ius sacrum*. In oldest times the *ius sacrum* exercised a considerable influence on private law, the knowledge of legal rules and their interpretation and applicability having been a monopoloy of the priests.

Problem is, the evidence behind such a reading is flimsy. I noticed this too when looking for evidence for the phrase in [PHI](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/1014/1/20/12270-12280#20):

> Naturae iura sacra sunt etiam apud piratas.
>
> The sacred laws of nature are also [found] among pirates.

There are so few references, that something like this thrown in is a dead giveaway that something is amiss. The *ius sacrum* here isn't a legal code, but simply a description of *ius*, it's really *ius naturae, quod sacrum etiam est*.

Johnson goes through the rest of the passages and cannot find either a legal or literary precedent for it. Instead, he thinks scholars have been conflating the terms *ius pontificium* and *ius sacrorum*, but there too are differences.

The *ius sacrorum* (attested as early as Cicero, e.g. *De Domo Sup* 41.1), or, perhaps, more correctly, the *iura sacrorum*, was a body of religious law that governed a family's *sacra*, holy objects, masks, *penates*, etc. These were the items that Romans used in conjunction with offerings to the gods, establishing a relationship between the *domus* and the divine. Unless I misunderstand the argument, the *ius sacrorum* that deal with public *sacra* would fall under the domain of the pontifical college, and thus part of the *ius pontificium*.

This latter *ius* is the broader one, and is encompassed by various sub-*iura* (e.g. *ius caerimoniarum*; see p. 112 for his reasons for concluding thus).

*All* of this so far is a type of *ius gentium*, man-made law that governs individual nations. The Roman implementation of the *ius sacrorum* or *ius caerimoniarum* would not necessary apply to the Greeks, Carthaginians, or Gauls. This can be contrasted though with the *ius naturale*, 'natural law', those laws (*sacra* in Seneca's opinion) which the gods gave mortals.

This is where *fas* and *nefas* come in. You don't need to make a specific law or listen to the advice of the *pontifices* to know that cannibalism is wrong. It's not just wrong on a technical or legal level, but *morally* wrong (cf. Ov. *Met.* 6.585). It's a broach of human nature, and the gods will not only punish you (which can happen from carelessness), but sentence you to [an eternity of torture in the underworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalus).

As such, *nefas* is not legalistic, but rather laws were created to address issues of *fas* and *nefas*, not that they necessarily needed to do so.

Comment: Many thanks! It seems that I wasn't completely off the mark (especially with *fas*), but this answer really changes the way I see these concepts. It starts making sense.

Comment: Ah, so that's where we get *nefarious*. I was trying to think of English derivatives of *fas*. Any others?

Comment: @ktm5124 Not directly, but it's related to *fare*, so words like *infant* are related.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this! I'm deeply curious what the Met reference is, though - which book? And which story?

Comment: @ariadnep I edited it to add the book in. It's book 6, the story of Procne, Philomela, and Tereus.